# object access without create array in php

Tags: php, arrays

```
class Car {


    function __construct() {
//        echo 'car con';
    }

    function setInfo($car_arr) {
            foreach ($car_arr as $key => $value) {
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }

    }

}
```

i try to access like bellow

```
$car1 = new Car();
$car1->setInfo('make', 'Toyota')->setInfo('model', 'scp10');
```

that gave to me bellow error

```
Call to a member function setInfo() on a non-object
```

how can i change setInfo() method call  `$car1->setInfo('make', 'Toyota')->setInfo('model', 'scp10');` after that car class set $make = 'Toyota', like that

how can i print this object like
bellow

```
make = Toyota
model = scp10
```

Comment: you got 2 problems in one question interesting...

Comment: Take a look at magic getters and setters to allow you to do things like `$car1->make = 'Toyota';`

Comment: You was so close and then you deleted the code you needed :(

Comment: Okay, I'm done. What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `return $this;` in the end of your method for chain-like calls.

Answer (score 1):

change the setInfo code to return itself like:

```
function setInfo($car_arr,$car_val=null) {

    if(is_array($car_arr)){
        foreach ($car_arr as $key => $value) {
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }else if(is_string($car_arr) && $car_val != null){
        $this->{$car_arr} = $car_val;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

now you can chain the functions because its returning itself.

also if you want to call it like you want ( like `$this->setInfo("make","Ford")`) you need to add an else on `is_array` and add an optional parameter like shown in the code above

Answer (score 1):

To combine all answers into one (well, except @EaterOfCorpses):

```
<?php
class Car {
  private $data = array();

  function setInfo(array $carInfo) {
    foreach ($carInfo as $k => $v) {
      $this->data[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  function __set($key, $val) {
    $this->data[$key] = $val;
  }
  function __get($key) {
    return $this->data[$key];
  }
}

$car = new Car();
$car->setInfo(['make' => 'Toyota', 'warranty' => '5 years']);
```

Note that there's no reason to `return $this` if you are setting all the properties at once.

Edited to add: also include magic getter/setter idea from Mark Baker just for the fun of it.

Comment: haha +1 for summing everything up and mentioning me :) also this code only works in PHP 5.4, in PHP 5.3 this way of creating an array will give errors

Comment: Got to further adoption with *something*. But you're correct it needs to read `array('make' => 'Toyota', 'warranty' => '5 years')` for PHP-5.3 instead

Comment: what you are doing now is impossible: `$this-${k} = $v;` needs to be `$this->{$k} = $v;`. test if it was possible: http://codepad.viper-7.com/amr3GS

Comment: You may want to post you answer here too ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546567/print-dynamicly-set-proprites-in-object I don't want to walk away with the points of the code of your answer

Comment: Uh, never seen this situation before. Isn't this question a badly worded duplicate of the one you linked?

Comment: Yes sir, it is. Flagged it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$car1->setInfo('make', 'Toyota')` only once. That's because you create a car, then set info, and then you want to set info to info, but you can't set info to info.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a [`fluent interface`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

Add

```
return $this;
```

as the last line of your setInfo() method

Answer (score 0):

Use array syntax: `$car1->setInfo(array('make', 'Toyota'))`

Answer (score 0):

You can return $this in your function (if you have php 5.4):

```
function setInfo($car_arr) {

   ...

   return $this;
}
```

Comment: is it not possible in lower versions?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses it's mistake, that's possible in lower PHP versions as well.