# print dynamicly set proprites in object

Tags: php

how to print dynamical add properties in bellow class?

```
class Car {

    function __construct() {
    }

    function setInfo($car_arr) {
            foreach ($car_arr as $key => $value) {
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
    }

   }
```

set class object like bellow

```
$car1 = new Car();
$car1->setInfo(array('make' => 'Toyota', 'model' => 'scp10'));

$car2 = new Car();
$car2->setInfo(array('anme1' => 'value1', 'anme2' => 'value2'));
```

now I want to to print car object bellow

```
make = Toyota
model = scp10
```

Comment: You can use `foreach` to iterate on your element (assuming that properties are not private)

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
$car1 = new Car();
$car1->setInfo(array('make' => 'Toyota', 'model' => 'scp10'));

echo $car1->make;
echo $car1->model;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    class Car {

        function __construct() {
        }

        function setInfo($car_arr) {
                foreach ($car_arr as $key => $value) {
                    $this->{$key} = $value;
                }
        }

       }
    $car1 = new Car();
    $car1->setInfo(array('make' => 'Toyota', 'model' => 'scp10'));

    echo "Make value is : " . $car1->make. ", Model value is : ". $car1->model;
?>
```

above code output `Make value is : Toyota, Model value is : scp10`

Answer (score 1):

Please consider storing the properties explicitly like I pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15545569/785663):

```
<?php
class Car {
  private $data = array();

  function setInfo(array $carInfo) {
    foreach ($carInfo as $k => $v) {
      $this->data[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $this;
  }

  function __set($key, $val) {
    $this->data[$key] = $val;
  }
  function __get($key) {
    return $this->data[$key];
  }
}

$car = new Car();
$car->setInfo(array('make' => 'Toyota', 'warranty' => '5 years'));
```

I'd consider it more "clean", but that's probably debatable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you look for something like this [PHP Magic Methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

For example this one:

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $var1;
    public $var2;

    public static function __set_state($an_array) // As of PHP 5.1.0
    {
        $obj = new A;
        $obj->var1 = $an_array['var1'];
        $obj->var2 = $an_array['var2'];
        return $obj;
    }
}

$a = new A;
$a->var1 = 5;
$a->var2 = 'foo';

eval('$b = ' . var_export($a, true) . ';'); // $b = A::__set_state(array(
                                            //    'var1' => 5,
                                            //    'var2' => 'foo',
                                            // ));
var_dump($b);

?>
```

[This](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) will be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch all properties using get_object_vars():

```
$vars = get_object_vars($car1);
foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . ' = ' . $value . '<br />';
}
```